# Возвращение элемента в исходное положение

Tags: html, jquery, css

Имеется заголовок, к которому прикручена иконка. При нажатии на неё контент блока сворачивается, а сама кнопка трансформами поворачивается на 90 градусов.

Как сделать так, чтобы при повторном нажатии на неё, когда контент разворачивается, она возвращалась в исходное положение?

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
  $('.fade-review-btn').click(function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $('.review-block-content').slideToggle();
  });
});
```

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
body {
  font-family: 'Open Sans';
}
.layout-center-wrapper {
  width: 500px;
  height: 300px;
  margin: 50px auto;
  padding: 1em;
  box-shadow: 0 0 10px rgba(0,0,0,.5);
}
.block-title {
    position: relative;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #191919;
    color: #191919;
}
.block-title h3 {
    display: inline;
    margin: 0 0 0 7px;
    padding: 0;
    font-size: 18px;
    color: #191919
}
.fade-icon {
    position: absolute;
    top: 8px;
    right: 0;
    width: 15px;
    height: 10px;
    background: url('http://tripedali.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/02/app-page-icons.png') -28px 0 no-repeat;
    transform: rotate(0deg);
    transition: ease-out all 150ms;
}
.fade-icon:focus {
    outline: none;
    transform: rotate(-90deg);
    transition: ease-in all 150ms;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="layout-center-wrapper">
  <div class="block-title">
    <i class="fa fa-thumbs-o-up"></i>
    <h3>WhatsApp Review</h3>
    <a class="fade-icon fade-review-btn" href="#close"></a>
  </div>

  <div class="review-block-content">
    <p>
      Today's smartphone is much the same as it used in the 2000s.
      The most significant difference between today's iOS and
      Android and former favorites Windows Mobile and Symbian is
      always being online. Old smartphones didn't have to be
      connected to the Internet all the time (as modern ones are).
    </p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

заменить :focus  на класс

```js
   $(function() {
     $('.fade-review-btn').click(function(e) {
       e.preventDefault();
       $(this).toggleClass('active')
       $('.review-block-content').slideToggle();
     });
   });
```

```css
  * {
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    box-sizing: border-box;
  }
  body {
    font-family: 'Open Sans';
  }
  .layout-center-wrapper {
    width: 500px;
    height: 300px;
    margin: 50px auto;
    padding: 1em;
    box-shadow: 0 0 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, .5);
  }
  .block-title {
    position: relative;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #191919;
    color: #191919;
  }
  .block-title h3 {
    display: inline;
    margin: 0 0 0 7px;
    padding: 0;
    font-size: 18px;
    color: #191919
  }
  .fade-icon {
    position: absolute;
    top: 8px;
    right: 0;
    width: 15px;
    height: 10px;
    background: url('http://tripedali.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/02/app-page-icons.png') -28px 0 no-repeat;
    -webkit-transform: rotate(0deg);
    -moz-transform: rotate(0deg);
    -o-transform: rotate(0deg);
    transform: rotate(0deg);
    -webkit-transition: ease-out all 150ms;
    -moz-transition: ease-out all 150ms;
    -o-transition: ease-out all 150ms;
    transition: ease-out all 150ms;
  }
  .fade-icon.active {
    outline: none;
    -webkit-transform: rotate(-90deg);
    -moz-transform: rotate(-90deg);
    -o-transform: rotate(-90deg);
    transform: rotate(-90deg);
    -webkit-transition: ease-in all 150ms;
    -moz-transition: ease-in all 150ms;
    -o-transition: ease-in all 150ms;
    transition: ease-in all 150ms;
  }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="layout-center-wrapper">
  <div class="block-title">
    <i class="fa fa-thumbs-o-up"></i>
    <h3>WhatsApp Review</h3>
    <a class="fade-icon fade-review-btn" href="#close"></a>
  </div>

  <div class="review-block-content">
    <p>
      Today's smartphone is much the same as it used in the 2000s. The most significant difference between today's iOS and Android and former favorites Windows Mobile and Symbian is always being online. Old smartphones didn't have to be connected to the Internet
      all the time (as modern ones are).
    </p>
  </div>
```

Answer (score 2):

Например, можно добавлять класс кнопке, а в сss поворачивать её:

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
  $('.fade-review-btn').click(function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $(this).toggleClass("closed");
    $('.review-block-content').slideToggle();
  });
});
```

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
body {
  font-family: 'Open Sans';
}
.layout-center-wrapper {
  width: 500px;
  height: 300px;
  margin: 50px auto;
  padding: 1em;
  box-shadow: 0 0 10px rgba(0,0,0,.5);
}
.block-title {
    position: relative;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #191919;
    color: #191919;
}
.block-title h3 {
    display: inline;
    margin: 0 0 0 7px;
    padding: 0;
    font-size: 18px;
    color: #191919
}
.fade-icon {
    position: absolute;
    top: 8px;
    right: 0;
    width: 15px;
    height: 10px;
    background: url('http://tripedali.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/02/app-page-icons.png') -28px 0 no-repeat;
    transform: rotate(0deg);
    transition: ease-out all 150ms;
}

.fade-review-btn.closed {
    transform: rotate(-90deg);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="layout-center-wrapper">
  <div class="block-title">
    <i class="fa fa-thumbs-o-up"></i>
    <h3>WhatsApp Review</h3>
    <a class="fade-icon fade-review-btn" href="#close"></a>
  </div>

  <div class="review-block-content">
    <p>
      Today's smartphone is much the same as it used in the 2000s.
      The most significant difference between today's iOS and
      Android and former favorites Windows Mobile and Symbian is
      always being online. Old smartphones didn't have to be
      connected to the Internet all the time (as modern ones are).
    </p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$(document).ready(function () {
  $('.fade-review-btn').click(function (e) {
    ...
    $(this).data("TRANS", !$(this).data("TRANS"));

   if($(this).data("TRANS") {
            // крутите в одну строну
    } else {
       // крутите в другую
   }

  });
});
```